# Smooth scrolling on mouse wheel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

Instead of the normal mouse scroll speed, I'd like to make it slower and smoother and as consistent as it can in modern browsers.

I have already tried using a few plugins like NiceScroll (https://nicescroll.areaaperta.com/).

But after installing it, for some reason it puts an overflow: hidden; on my content and can't scroll anywhere after. I don't need any custom-designed scrollbars. I just need the scrolling to be smoother when using the mouse scroll or vertical scroll bar like this:

http://pervolo.com/

Would anyone please enlighten me about this? I plan to use the skrollr plugin (https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) along with the smooth scrolling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may get you going:

```
$(window).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
  var dir,
      amt = 100;

  e.preventDefault();
  if(e.type === 'mousewheel') {
    dir = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 ? '-=' : '+=';
  }
  else {
    dir = e.originalEvent.detail < 0 ? '-=' : '+=';
  }      

  $('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: dir + amt
  },500, 'linear');
})
```

`DOMMouseScroll` and `e.originalEvent.detail` are required for Firefox.  Change `amt` to be your desired scroll distance, and change `500` to be your desired scroll speed.

Fiddle:  **http://jsfiddle.net/utcsdyp1/1**

Comment: some error when page ended :( specially when speed is small than amt.

Comment: @mohsensolhnia, I've tried different values for the speed and `amt`, but I don't see any errors.  Can you grab the error from your console and let me know what browser you're using?

Comment: no text error, but when i use laptop touchpad mouse and when i scrolling down to end of page then 30 or 40 second i must wait to it again receive my command( scroll up or down). i set amd=30 and speed=5, it work well ;D,but another problem, very slow when i use real mouse wheel :(    you know well that people use different mouse wheel speed. as i think, we need a function that return user mouse wheel speed. i never use your js only in my localhost, it must act in users browsers.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't have a touchpad to test on, but if you find a solution, it may be useful to other people.

Comment: @mohsensolhnia, ahh, the purpose of my post was to show the OP how to accomplish smooth scrolling, but I understand that it might be too slow at the current speed.  (I was trying to duplicate the functionality of the pervolo site.)  However, your comment re "30 or 40 second" made me realize that I should *stop* the animation before starting a new one.  My update may help resolve that problem at least.  Appreciate the feedback!

Comment: Can we get smoothness like this website have ?

http://www.sezane.com/denim

Comment: @Md Abu Ahsan Basir, if you need clarification or if something isn't working, please post it as a comment rather than editing my post.  Thanks.

Comment: @kapil, I'm afraid I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded in making the scroll by mouse wheel look smooth as butter! Copy-paste the following snippet and try yourself.

```
let easeInOutQuint = t => t<.5 ? 16*t*t*t*t*t : 1+16*(--t)*t*t*t*t; // Easing function found at https://gist.github.com/gre/1650294

// With this attempt I tried to make the scroll by mouse wheel look smooth
let delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
let dy = 0;
window.addEventListener("wheel", async e => {

    // Prevent the default way to scroll the page
    e.preventDefault();

    dy += e.deltaY;
    let _dy = dy; // Store the value of "dy"
    await delay(150); // Wait for .15s

    // If the value hasn't changed during the delay, then scroll to "start + dy"
    if (_dy === dy) {
        let start = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset;
        customScrollTo(start + dy, 600, easeInOutQuint);
        dy = 0;
    }
}, { passive: false });

function customScrollTo(to, duration, easingFunction) {
    let start = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset;

    let time = Date.now();
    let timeElapsed = 0;

    let speed = (to - start) / duration;
    
    (function move() {

        if (timeElapsed > duration) {
            return;
        }

        timeElapsed = Date.now() - time;

        // Get the displacement of "y"
        let dy = speed * timeElapsed;
        let y = start + dy;

        // Map "y" into a range from 0 to 1
        let _y = (y - start) / (to - start);
        // Fit "_y" into a curve given by "easingFunction"
        _y = easingFunction(_y);
        // Expand "_y" into the original range
        y = start + (to - start) * _y;

        window.scrollTo(0, y);
        window.requestAnimationFrame(move);
    })();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can catch an action when user scrolls using `$(element).on( "scroll", handler )`, then, using, for example this code

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#target-element").offset().top
}, 1000);
```

scroll to some element using jQuery

Comment: I know. I'm already using my own version of that code. What I need is not having a target element. If you have seen the site above: http://pervolo.com/, I meant when using the mouse scroll, there's this smooth effect instead of the jumpy default one of browsers.

Comment: You can prevent page from scrolling, than scroll the document on certain number of pixels

Comment: How exactly do I do that? Can you please edit your answer and let me know how it works in jquery code? Thanks. :)